# I can add data with SQLite but i can't see on DB Browser in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, dart

I can connect SQLite Database with DB Browser in Flutter. I can't update DB Browser when i added data but i can see data in terminal . I don't understand. Database is working ,i can retrieve data and i can see in flutter .  I want to see on DB Browser when to add data.
‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎

My db folder (database.db) in assets

> DB helper here

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static const String databaseName = 'database.db';

  Future<Database> initDatabase() async {
    var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    //join(await getDatabasesPath());

    var path = join(documentDirectory.path, databaseName);
    if (await databaseExists(path)) {
      print('database zaten var');
    } else {

      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/database.db');
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      print("veritabanı kopyalandı");
    }
    return openDatabase(path);
  }














     
  Future<void> insertData(
    int role,
    String username,
    String name,
    String lastname,
    String password,
    int permissions,
    int location,
  ) async {
    var db = await initDatabase();
    var data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data = {
      'ROLE': role,
      'USERNAME': username.toString(),
      'NAME': name.toString(),
      'LASTNAME': lastname.toString(),
      'PASSWORD': password.toString(),
      'PERMISSIONS': permissions,
      'LOCATION': location,
    };
    await db.insert("USERS", data);
    print(data);
  }
}
```

> and this is flutter code

````
Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: CustomProgressButton(
                      
                          onPressed: () async {
                            _addUserAlert(context);
                           

                            await DatabaseHelper().insertData(
                              role ,
                              addUserControllers[0].text,
                              addUserControllers[1].text,
                              addUserControllers[2].text,
                              addUserControllers[3].text,
                              1020,
                              52,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                    ),```

> this is pubsc


`
name: maui
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  go_router: ^10.0.0
  sqflite: ^2.3.0
  dio: ^5.3.2
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  anim_search_bar: ^2.0.3
  riverpod: ^2.3.7
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.7
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  pay: ^1.1.2
  path: ^1.8.3
  flutter_toastr: ^1.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

 
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/database.db
    - assets/deneme.db
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

 
`


I can connect SQLite Database with DB Browser in Flutter. I can't update DB Browser when i added data but i can see data in terminal . I don't understand. Database is working ,i can retrieve data and i can see in flutter .  I want to see on DB Browser when to add data.
````